# How can I make this more Pythonic?

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm working on a function to find a string in a set that best matches a given date.  I've decided to do it with a scoring system kind of like CSS selectors because it has the same concept of specificity.

One part is to figure out the min score.  If I'm looking for a date (year month day), then the min score is 100.  If I'm looking for a month (just month and year), then it's 10, and if I only have a year, then it's 1:

```
minscore = 1
if month: minscore = 10
if day: minscore = 100
```

I'm pretty new to Python, so I don't know all the tricks.  How can I make this more (the most) Pythonic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview.se]

Comment: I'd say Pythonic isn't always about eliminating code lines, it's also about making the code easier to read. Your code may not be as concise as it can be, but I can read it more easily than most ways to write it shorter.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I feel Code Review is mainly targeted for large amounts of code that needs to be reviewed. Small snippets like these are fine? See [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108867/code-review-and-stack-overflow-overlap) but I could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ternary expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
minscore = 100 if day else 10 if month else 1
```

From [pep-308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)(Conditional expression):

> The motivating use case was the prevalance of error-prone attempts
>       to achieve the same effect using "and" and "or".

Answer (score 3):

Stick to easily-readable code:

```
if day:
    minscore = 100
elif month:
    minscore = 10
else:
    minscore = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Sparse is better than dense ;)

```
minscore = 1
if month:
    minscore = 10
elif day:
    minscore = 100
```

This is also quoted in the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are
>   generally discouraged.
>
> Yes:

```
if foo == 'blah':
    do_blah_thing() do_one() do_two() do_three()
```

> Rather not:

```
if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing() do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
```

---

I guess a conditional statement (i.e the ternary expression) is probably the way to go for the "most pythonic", but I thought a quote from the Zen of Python would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me... because I started with a bit more complicated (buggy) minscore algorithm, I didn't see the answer at first.  I think this is pretty good:

```
minscore = day and 100 or month and 10 or 1
```

Comment: This is much harder to read than your original version. I'd say it is much less Pythonic.

Comment: @svk Fair enough.  Like I said, I'm still learning even what it means to be "Pythonic".

Comment: From [pep-308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)(ternary expression): *The motivating use case was the prevalance of error-prone attempts to achieve the same effect using "and" and "or"*